# Gradle copy creates an empty file

Tags: file-io, gradle

I have a multi-project gradle build that copies some source files from the parent project into the build directory and then attempts to overwrite a token in one of the copied files. Everything runs OK but the file ends up being empty. Here's the file snippet with the template to replace:

```
---
# file: clients.yaml
#properties shared by all client machines

jmeter_version: "${jmeterVersion}"
```

Here's snippet of gradle.properties:

```
jmeterVersion=3.0
```

And here are two tasks that suppose to do the trick

```
/** This task copies files from pdo-shared */
task copyFromCommonProject(type:Copy, dependsOn: configurations.commonProjectContent){
    from configurations.commonProjectContent.collect{ zipTree(it) }
    into "$buildDir"
    /*doLast {
        updateAnsibleTokens.execute()
    }*/
}

task updateAnsibleTokens(type: Copy, dependsOn: copyFromCommonProject) {
   from "$buildDir/commons/ansible/group_vars/clients.yml"
   into "$buildDir/commons/ansible/group_vars/"
   expand(jmeterVersion: "$jmeterVersion")
}
```

I run this from the parent project as `gradle clean :tpcds-benchmark:updateAnsibleTokens`

First tasks copies all the files where and as expected it's the 2nd task that does not work

Please notice commented out `doLast` section. I tried to run these two tasks as `gradle clean :tpcds-benchmark:copyFromCommonProject` by uncommenting `doLast` section and removing `dependsOn: copyFromCommonProject` from the 2nd task

In both instances client.yml ends up completely empty

**P.S.** Even if I disable `expand(jmeterVersion: "$jmeterVersion")` line I will get an empty file. With some more tests it seems that copying a file on itself will generate an empty file so perhaps I'm just doing it wrong. The same code I have will work if I only change the destination directory

Comment: the second task looks as if it tries to copy file over itself (as source and target point to same file). Is it intended?

Comment: Yes. The original file contains a token that needs to be updated as result of the 2nd task

Comment: @NikitaSkvortsov please see P.S. in the original post

Comment: Solved. Will add answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I had to [reread this manual section](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html) to understand the lifecycle better.

Following my original example here's 2 tasks that will work as intended. The problem as I started to suspect was that attempt to copy and modify `client.yml` was happening in the configuration cycle before the actual copying from the source was happening. Adding `<<` for the 2nd task ensured that the modification was happening in the execution cycle after the original file was copied

```
/** This task copies files from pdo-shared */
task copyFromCommonProject(type:Copy, dependsOn: configurations.commonProjectContent){
    from configurations.commonProjectContent.collect{ zipTree(it) }
    into "$buildDir"
}

task updateAnsibleTokens(type: Copy, dependsOn: copyFromCommonProject) << {
   from "$buildDir/commons/ansible/group_vars/clients.yml"
   into "$buildDir/commons/ansible/group_vars/"
   expand(jmeterVersion: "$jmeterVersion")
}
```

Comment: In this particular case you don't need `<<` for `updateAnsibleTokens` task. This task is of type `Copy` so `from` and `into` will be run in configuration phase.

Comment: If I skip << then I get an empty file, did you read the question?

Comment: Then is doesn't make sense to assign `Copy` type to this task - it will be much better to just use `copy {}` method invoked on project instance. Also it seems that a single task will be sufficient.

Comment: I have a limited experience with Gradle, you are welcome to answer the question and if your one method solution works I will gladly accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, why adding the `<<` helped. Nevertheless, doing expand while extracting archive feels much more natural:

```
task copyFromCommonProject(type:Copy, dependsOn: configurations.commonProjectContent) {
    from configurations.commonProjectContent.collect {
         zipTree(it)
    }
    exclude "commons/ansible/group_vars/clients.yml"
    with copySpec {
         from configurations.commonProjectContent.collect {
              zipTree(it)
         }
         include "commons/ansible/group_vars/clients.yml"
         expand(jmeterVersion: "$jmeterVersion")
    }
    into "$buildDir"
}
```

Comment: Tried it just now. Ended up with empty group_vars folder

Comment: I think `<<` works because without it the 2nd copy happens in the same configuration stage and before the actual file is copied to the disk. By pushing it to the execution stage I simply ensure that the 2nd copy is executed after the initial copying is done

Comment: what confuses me is the fact, that  no copying is perfomed at evaluation stage and the `<<` should have only one effect: modify settings of Copy task _after_ copying is already done

Comment: The only thing I can say based on my limited knowledge (and my tests) is that my solution works and yours doesn't